Facebook API Cannot parse access token when providing token generate by IOS flutter app
When I try to hit
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={{token}}

using the access token generated from flutter facebook auth on IOS it returns error
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 190,
        "fbtrace_id": "A7VLOSLTiXhbqehRbUpNz7z"
    }
}

however when I try to generate token from android device and use it in the same endpoint it works fine.
I downgraded flutter facebook auth and same issue still occurs
